# Cancelling BackgroundWorker - Windows Forms (C++/CLI)

Tags: .net, winforms, c++-cli, backgroundworker

I am triggering `CancelAsync()` method on a button click event to stop a Background Worker in my Windows Form code. The following is the sample code,

```
// Windows Form

private: System::Void startButton_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
        testBgWorker->RunWorkerAsync();
        }

private: System::Void testBgWorker_DoWork(System::Object^  sender, System::ComponentModel::DoWorkEventArgs^  e) {

            CalculateDistance* calcDistance = new CalculateDistance();
        calcDistance->doCalculations();
         }

private: System::Void stopButton_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

            testBgWorker->CancelAsync();
         }

// CalculateDistance.cpp   

void CalculateDistance::doCalculations() {
    for (int i=0; i<1000, i++) 
    {
        // some calculations here
    }
}
```

How can I cancel the BackgroundWorker (exit from `for` loop)? `CancelAsync()` doesn't seem to do the job.

Thanks.

Comment: Use tags to specify programming language, not the title. It enables syntax highlighting and helps the right people find the question.

Comment: You don't check the CancellationPending property anywhere in your worker code.  So no, it won't cancel.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you, I somehow missed to notice the `CancellationPending` property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check for cancel in the CalulateDistance loop.  In C# it looks like this.   Some good examples on msdn.microsoft.com.  And you need to mark the backgoundworker as support cancelling.

```
 if (worker.CancellationPending)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            return "cancelled";
        }
```