# Cancelling BackgroundWorker in C++/CLI wrapper of native C++ loop

Tags: c++, .net, c++-cli, backgroundworker

Like this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10723045/cancelling-backgroundworker-windows-forms-c-cli/15760410) I need to cancel a BackgroundWorker in a C++/CLI class derived from a .NET BackgroundWorker.

I am using C++/CLI to wrap a long running, legacy, native C++ function.

How can/should I access the CancellationPending member of the BackgoundWorker class from the long running loop in the native C++?

```
public ref class BackgroundWorkerWrapper : BackgroundWorker
{
    private:
        Outline* pOutline;

    public:
        BackgroundWorkerWrapper(void) 
        {
            WorkerReportsProgress = true;

            pOutline = new Outline;

    //      pOutline->CancellationPending = &(BackgroundWorker::CancellationPending);

        }

    protected:

        virtual void OnDoWork(DoWorkEventArgs ^e) override {
            pOutline->DoWork();
            BackgroundWorker::OnDoWork(e);
        }

    };
```

Above you can see I have tried to map the CancellationPending to a bool in the Outline class. So far this has not worked.

My Outline class is fairly straight forward.

```
public class Outline
{

public:
    bool* CancellationPending;

    Outline()
    {
    }
    ~Outline()
    {
    }

    void DoWork()
    {
        try
        {
            for (int i=0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                if (CancellationPending[0] == true)
                {
                    break;
                }

                // Do some trivial work
                Sleep(50);
            }
        }
        // catch(...)
              catch (exception& e)
        {
            cout << e.what() << endl;
        }

    }
};
```

Alternately is there another way to add another handler to the CancelAsnc() function of the BackgroundWorker class that could somehow set a cancel variable in the outline class?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could add something to the end of your `OnDoWork` override to continuously check the `BackgroundWorker::CancellationPending` flag. If true, set `pOutline->CancellationPending` to true too.